# How to print rows in a json that have a duplicated column value?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file like this

```
{"places": [{"place_name":"123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL","address":"809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A","city": "PEORIA","state":"IL","zip":"61615","geo_location":"40.78878653,-89.605669034","data": {}},{"place_name":"123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL","address":"6501 SOUTH 12TH ST","city":"PORTAGE","state":"MI","zip":"49024","geo_location":"42.220381633,-85.646607261","data": {}}, {"place_name": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.", "address": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.", "city": "LANSING", "state": "IL", "zip": "60438", "geo_location": "41.565952019,-87.556316006", "data": {}}]}
```

As you can see the first two "place_name" values are the same and I would like those to be printed. Here is the code I have thus far but all I get a Nan. Can anyone help with this?

```
import pandas as pd

places = pd.read_json("test.json")
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(places, columns = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'geo', 'data'])
duplicatedRowsDF = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated(["name"])]
print(duplicatedRowsDF)
```

Here is the output

```
   name  address  city  state  zip  geo  data
1   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
2   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

my desired output would just be the name of the columns with duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> from pandas import json_normalize
>>>
>>> json_data = {"places": [{"place_name":"123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL","address":"809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A","city": "PEORIA","state":"IL","zip":"61615","geo_location":"40.78878653,-89.605669034","data": {}},{"place_name":"123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL","address":"6501 SOUTH 12TH ST","city":"PORTAGE","state":"MI","zip":"49024","geo_location":"42.220381633,-85.646607261","data": {}}, {"place_name": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.", "address": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.", "city": "LANSING", "state": "IL", "zip": "60438", "geo_location": "41.565952019,-87.556316006", "data": {}}]}
>>>
>>> df = json_normalize(json_data, record_path='places')
>>> df
               place_name                    address     city state    zip                geo_location
0  123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL  809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A   PEORIA    IL  61615   40.78878653,-89.605669034
1  123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL         6501 SOUTH 12TH ST  PORTAGE    MI  49024  42.220381633,-85.646607261
2  18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.     18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.  LANSING    IL  60438  41.565952019,-87.556316006
```

The columns `place_name` and `state` have duplicates. Below are two ways to get those column names as a `list` (having the column names you can get the rows of `df` with duplicates using `df[df[<column name(s)>].duplicated(keep=False)]`):

```py
>>> df.columns[df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated).any()].to_list() # close to what you have, i.e., apply `duplicated` to each column
['place_name', 'state']
>>> 
>>> [c for c in df.columns if not df[c].is_unique] # another way
['place_name', 'state']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicate place names like so :

```
import collections
place_names = [item['place_name'] for item in places['places']]
print([item for item, count in collections.Counter(place_names).items() if count > 1])
```

this will print `['123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL']`